# yq - add into a list that has custom types

Tags: yaml, yq

```
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      FunctionName: myFunction
      Policies:
        - !Ref Policy1
```

I have an example yaml as such, and I'd like to append `Policy2` into the Policies block for all resources that has `Type: AWS::Serverless::Function`

Following is the command I have:
 `yq '(.Resources.[] | select(.Type=="AWS::Serverless::Function") | .Properties.Policies) += ["!Ref Policy2"]' example.yaml`

And this ends up with:

```
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      FunctionName: myFunction
      Policies:
        - !Ref Policy1
        - '!Ref Policy2'
```

Where `!Ref Policy2` is single quoted. Any guidance on how I can append the policy without it being single quoted?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!Ref` is a tag, and not part of the string value. Set it explicitly:

```bash
yq '
  (.Resources.[] | select(.Type=="AWS::Serverless::Function").Properties.Policies
  ) += ["Policy2" | . tag = "!Ref"]
' example.yaml
```

```yaml
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      FunctionName: myFunction
      Policies:
        - !Ref Policy1
        - !Ref Policy2
```